# Laravel deploy project and remove project name from url?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to remove my project name from URL.
e.g My project name is `xyz` and domain name is `sampledomain.com`. 
So instead of `sampledomain.com/xyz` url I want my project should run as `sampledomain.com`.

I have successfully removed public from url but not able to remove project name.
What I need to change in `htaccess` and `index.php` file.

I have put my `.htaccess` and `index.php` file in `sampledomain.com` means outside the root folder.

Here is my `.htaccess` file

> Blockquote
>   
>       
>           Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

and `index.php` (paths)

`require __DIR__ . '/xyz/bootstrap/autoload.php';`

and

`$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/xyz/bootstrap/app.php';`

This could be a repetitive question but I have found answer only to remove public folder from the URL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't change anything in `.htaccess` or `index.php`. You adjust your webserver to point at the `public` directory as its document root.

Comment: Don't even try to move `public` to your webservers public folder. You have to point your webserver to use `public` as root.

Comment: I have added my htaccess and index.php file. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Is this on a shared hosting site?
You really shouldn't have to modify the htaccess file.
In your index.php file I'm assuming you're one step above the root directory for your web app.
So to make it so your site is in the form www.foo.com and not www.foo.com/app, if this weren't a shared site you may have something like htdocs on an Apache server and your htaccess and index and everything else in your public folder would sit here and not in some other directory to make it www.foo.com/app

If your index.php were sitting directly in htdocs then the bootstrap path would be

```
require __DIR__ . '../YOUR_APP_NAME/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__ . '../YOUR_APP_NAME/bootstrap/app.php';
```

You just need the two dots to direct the file path to your application

The file structure in this example would be

```
/xampp/htdocs/htaccess
/xampp/htdocs/index.php
/xampp/htdocs/js/
/xampp/htdocs/css/
```

This would all be under the domain www.DOMAIN.com
Your app would sit under `/xampp/YOUR_APP_NAME/`

Everything under htdocs is the domain of your website

If you were to have www.domain.com/YOUR_APP_NAME

The file structure would look like this

```
/xampp/htdocs/YOUR_APP_NAME/htaccess
/xampp/htdocs/YOUR_APP_NAME/index.php
/xampp/htdocs/YOUR_APP_NAME/js/
/xampp/htdocs/YOUR_APP_NAME/css/
```

Which would give you the www.domain.com/YOUR_APP_NAME
and your index.php would look like the following

```
require __DIR__ . '../../YOUR_APP_NAME/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__ . '../../YOUR_APP_NAME/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Notice we are now backing out twice in the file structure because of the extra directory /YOUR_APP_NAME/

Don't get confused by /xampp/htdocs/YOUR_APP_NAME/ and /xampp/YOUR_APP_NAME/ They are not the same they just share the same name.

Comment: I dont want my app name should be display in url. I want my app should run using my domain name like `www.DOMAIN.com`

Comment: Then follow my steps, the code you provided showed that you're not directing your app correctly.